# HTML/JS - From TOP: Another uncaught typeerror post

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Put simply, I've tried the async and defer methods, as well as moving the script tag, to try to get dom manipulation to work. I think it might just be the code since neither are solving the issue. I copy pasted code directly from an example on The Odin Project, so I'm not quite sure what's going wrong. Below are the HTML and JS files.

```js
const container = document.querySelector('#container');

const content = document.createElement('div');
content.classList.add('content');
content.textContent = 'This is the glorious text-content!';

container.appendChild(content);

const para = document.createElement('p');
para.classList.add('para');
para.textContent = 'This is the fun times!';

container.appendChild(para);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <title>DOM Manipulation</title>
  <script defer src="index.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>
    THE TITLE OF YOUR WEBPAGE
  </h1>
  <div className="container"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

To be more specific, the entire section after the first appendChild is basically useless, and could be removed for the time being. The specific error is "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'appendChild')" at index.js:8:11.

I've tried changing the way I write the code as well, but I cannot understand why this is an issue even when moving the script link to the bottom and using async + defer all at the same time. I've tried every combo of the 3 solutions but I cannot get this to work.

I cannot quite figure out why it seems that the DOM is forcing itself to load faster than the HTML despite whatever I try to do to slow it down. I also did clear my cache, multiple times even, just to make sure it wasn't a cache issue. I was running this test with the live server extension, making sure to save, and I even tried it loading as a local file instead.

At first, I had actually gotten the top part to work by mistyping the createElement("div") as a querySelector("div"), but then I tried to create the next element (the P) and that's when I noticed that there was an error in the console when trying to see why my P wasn't working (lol).

I know there are also some other potential fixes, the window.onload (idk the real spelling) and the addEventListener for when the window loads, but why would defer/async/bottom of HTML not work? It does not make any sense and I do not want to simply move on without understanding the issue.

Comment: `className="container"` should be `id="container"`.

Comment: @Barmar Thank you for fixing the code blocks, I didn't really know how the code snippet thing worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a wrong class attribute and selector, fix:

```
className="container" -> class="container"
```

and

```
querySelector('#container') -> querySelector('.container')`
```

```js
const container = document.querySelector('.container');

const content = document.createElement('div');
content.classList.add('content');
content.textContent = 'This is the glorious text-content!';

container.appendChild(content);

const para = document.createElement('p');
para.classList.add('para');
para.textContent = 'This is the fun times!';

container.appendChild(para);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <title>DOM Manipulation</title>
  <script defer src="index.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>
    THE TITLE OF YOUR WEBPAGE
  </h1>
  <div class="container"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

or

```
className="container" -> id="container"
```

```js
const container = document.querySelector('#container');

const content = document.createElement('div');
content.classList.add('content');
content.textContent = 'This is the glorious text-content!';

container.appendChild(content);

const para = document.createElement('p');
para.classList.add('para');
para.textContent = 'This is the fun times!';

container.appendChild(para);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <title>DOM Manipulation</title>
  <script defer src="index.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>
    THE TITLE OF YOUR WEBPAGE
  </h1>
  <div id="container"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I commented on the other person's post as well after reading yours first, so thank you for helping me out. I ended up fixing via the first option of changing both to keep it consistent with "classes" for the duration of the DOM exercise I'm working on, especially since I usually use classes instead of IDs anyways.

Comment: @tylerfire you should accept an answer (the checkbox) that solves your problem, that's how stackoverflow works. the other post you commented seems generated by chartGPT and that's prohibited on stackoverflow (that's considered cheating)

Comment: Yeah, just accepted the answer. I was waiting for the timer to let me accept it so I walked away for a water and came back late. As for the AI generated answers, I agree that it shouldn't be allowed on the website as it can create clutter, so I obv gave you the check.

Answer (score -1):

Based on the code you provided, the issue seems to be in how you're selecting the container in your JavaScript.

In your HTML:

In your JS:

```
const container = document.querySelector('#container');
```

You're trying to select an element with the ID container, but you've given your div a class of container in the HTML. The correct selector for a class is . (dot) and for an ID is # (hash).

To fix the error, you can do one of the following:

Change the class to an ID in your HTML:

```
<div id="container"></div>
```

Change your JavaScript to select using the class:

```
const container = document.querySelector('.container');
```

If you go with the first solution, your current JS code will work without changes. If you go with the second solution, you only need to change that one line in your JS.

Once you make this change, the error should be resolved, and the DOM manipulation will work as expected, even with defer on the script tag.

Regarding your question on defer, async, and script placement:

defer: This attribute tells the browser to execute the script after the HTML is parsed. It guarantees that scripts will be executed in the order they appear in the document.

async: This attribute tells the browser to execute the script as soon as it's available, which could be before or after the HTML is parsed. The order of execution for scripts loaded asynchronously is not guaranteed.

Placing the script at the bottom of the : This ensures that the HTML above the script has been parsed before the script runs.

In your case, using defer should have been enough, since it ensures that the script runs after the HTML is parsed. The issue was with the wrong selector in your JS code.

Try this and let me know.